# No display network configuration when installing Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, system-installation

I'm installing Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS on my Macbook 2015. In the first installing procedure, installer doesn't display IPv4 method and only displays `Create bond` at Network connections step.

I've checked some information, but every site and book indicate to set up IPv4 address at the Network config step. So does this mean that my PC cannot recognize the network interface?

If so, I have to edit network config by `/etc/netplan/99-config.yaml` after installing, right? Or this status is extraordinary, and I'm somehow wrong?

I'm not good at network configuration. Please teach me.